# StreamReader reads \u00fc but Postman reads OK

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, postman, soapui, fallback

Probably duplicate question but I couldn't find an answer for my problem. I have this code to call a web service:

```
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://172.21.122.1:5001/autocomplete");

        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        //tried this too: httpWebRequest.Accept = "gzip, deflate";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write("{ \"message\" : \"mü\" }");
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        response = "";
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

But no matter what Encoding I tried with StreamReader() c'tor, I get this response or worse: {"words":["m\u00fc\u015fteri","m\u00fc\u015fterisiyim""]}

When I use Postman or SoapUI to call the same service with the same request: {"message": "mü"}, 
response looks ok: {"words": ["müşteri","müşterisiyim"]}

Strange thing is: The same code works OK with many other services. It is only this specific service that the reponse is not correctly encoded. We believe there is a programming error with the service, but what I wonder is how Postman or SoapUI handles this. There should be a control in their code and if the response contains "\uxxxx", then Postman or SoapUI decodes it again.

I've checked all request / response headers in Postman and SoapUI with no luck. What can be the reason?

[image: Postman screen]
[image: SoapUI screen]

Comment: I notice you're not actually looking at the Body in Postman...? The Postman screenshot just shows the headers, but the C# is trying to read the body

Comment: Your response body looks reasonably well-formed as well: it starts with `{"words": ["`, which is valid JSON, and most likely means the character encoding is fine, there's no compression, etc. The string itself is probably fine too: if you replace the `\uxxxx` with the actual characters they represent, you get `müşeri` and `müşterisiyim`, which Google Translate tells me is valid Turkish

Comment: How does the request object look like? Maybe there is a problem with encoding of the "words" content if you are loading it from somewhere outside.

Comment: I've edited the question and added request/response I'm using in both my code and Postman.

Comment: So from where the string "mü" comes from? I would bet that origin of it causes a problem - to check it quickly you can hard-code that request  and check the result.

Comment: The value "mü"  is already hardcoded.

Comment: I've edited the question to hardcode the values.

Comment: Would `Regex.Unescape(response)` or even `response = Regex.Unescape( streamReader.ReadToEnd());` resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex.Unescape(response) worked like a charm, thanks JosefZ!

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that your request is encoded correctly:
Set the Content Type to:

```
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
```

Check if request body is also UTF-8 encoded. Set the StreamWriter encoding to UTF-8 as well:

```
...

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.UTF8))

...
```

If you are getting the request content from other source, make sure to read it also using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I don't think this is correct: as discussed in the comments, the response looks well-formed

Comment: Yes, the response is well formed, the problem is that it is wrongly encoded.

Comment: I don't think that is the case -- you can see that it starts with valid JSON. If the encoding was wrong, that wouldn't happen.

Comment: This didn't work: the response still looks the same: {"words":["m\u00fc\u015fteri","m\u00fc\u015fterisiyim""]}

Comment: Try  setting the StreamWriter encoding to UTF-8 as well.

Comment: It didn't work either to set StreamWriter encoding to UTF-8.